# No error, but the For Loop does not print

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, printing

For a computer science project I am trying to make a game called snake using python, which the snake itself is represented by three XXX's that is printed onto an array. The snake also grows after 5 turns.

My question is concerning how to make a "For Loop" that iterates over the points in the snake and for each point in the snake, draws a new X on the board.

This is my code for that loop:

```
for i in snake:

    board[i[0]] [i[1]] = "X"

    return snake.pop()

print(snake)
```

No error shows up and the board is printed, but the snake (represented as XXX) is not printed. **What is wrong with this for loop?**

Additional information:

1. I have a function that takes a size and returns an array of that size
2. A function that takes a number of rows and a n number of columns and returns a board
3. A function that displays a board.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
def createArray(size):
    return ["_"] * size


def createBoard(rows, cols):
        matrix = createArray(rows)
        for i in range(rows):
                matrix[i] = createArray(cols)
        return matrix

def displayBoard(m):
        for i in range(len(m)):
                for j in range(len(m[0])):
                        print(m[i][j], end=" ")

                print()

def main():
    snake = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]]

    board = createBoard(20,30)
    displayBoard(board)

    for i in snake:
        board[i[0]][i[1]] = "X"
        return snake
    print(snake)

main()
```

Comment: please provide more information. Like are you using python, javascript?

Comment: where is the loop? where is the code? what language is this? properly tag this question please, provide complete sample

Comment: What do you think the `return snake.pop()` line is accomplishing?

Comment: Super easy to see there's a return snake.pop() that finishes the process. I'm not sure what are you trying to do there.

Comment: My instructor advised me to put that in there somewhere so that later I could use it to take the end of the snake and then add another "X" to the front of the snake. This would make the snake "move". I am not sure on how to use pop.() correctly.

Comment: @LethargicHamster [pop()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) simply returns the last element in the list. I think it's important to understand why you are doing something rather than blindly listening.

Comment: @aug The problem is the class if not taught or structure good at all. I have to salvage any information I can and piece it together , whether I know how to use it or not. What about now? I took out pop.() and used a different version that still produces no error, but it does not print the snake.